# Getting error, timeout value connect is not int when using selenium4 python3 edge 117 webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, microsoft-edge

I am writing a script in python3.11 to automate edge (version=117) in selenium4.  Upon executing the statement

```py
driver = webdriver.Edge(r'c:\edge_web\msedgedriver.exe')
```

a command window pops up and I receive a traceback saying that the timeout value connect was `<object object at 0x0000024D34055520>, but it must be an int, float or None`. I have not seen solutions as to how to set the value nor what is causing the error.

I tried adding options,

```py
driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path=r"c:\edge_web\msedgedriver.exe", options=edge_opts)
```

to set the connect value to an int.  But, got another error, got an unexpected keyword argument 'option'.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have used the correct Edge class like:

```
from selenium import webdriver

edge_opts = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
```

instead of `from msedge.selenium_tools import EdgeOptions`

If the issue continues, you may need to reinstall the Selenium library.